# Google Sheet: "Custom formula" condition in Filters

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I set a "Custom formula" condition in Filter (Data/Filter). I am using this formula the filter results that contains the strings "included1" and "included2" which works as expected:

```
=OR(REGEXMATCH(A:A,"included1"),REGEXMATCH(A:A,"included2"))
```

But I aslo need to exclude some strings. I tried with this, but not working:

```
=OR(REGEXMATCH(A:A,"included1"),REGEXMATCH(A:A,"included2")),NOT(REGEXMATCH(A:A,"not-included1"),REGEXMATCH(A:A,"not-included2"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=(REGEXMATCH(A:A,"included1|included2")*(NOT(REGEXMATCH(A:A,"not-included1|not-included2"))))
```

- *AND condition `*` added*